# where is the original json document stored in lucene through elasticsearch on disk(linux-ubuntu)

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, lucene, logstash, kibana

after reading blogs I came to know that data is stored on lucene and only metadata stored in elasticsearch

when we index a doc through elasticsearch , we store inverted index in segment but somewhere we need to store the json doc which will be retrieved . I'm unable to figure out the location on disk after going  through several blogs also.

Note - /var/lib/elasticsearh/data(mentioned in official doc and in stackoverflow question)   not exists in ubuntu

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not supposed to go retrieve the document on the disk, you have to go through elasticsearch to retrieve your document.

Comment: Got you! thanks @baudsp , but I'm curious to know where is the exact location the JSON file is stored ? is it deliberately hidden by elastic team

Comment: I don't think it is stored as a json file, I think it's converted in a binary format. And I think the decision of hiding the files behind the API is to protect the integrity of the content, especially when working with replicated content (so that all nodes have the same content.

Comment: Also if you change the data on the disk directly, the inverted index won't be valid anymore.

Comment: oh got you, can you post this as an answer so that it could be helpful to others in community

Comment: If you wish. I concatenated and cleaned up my comments.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to go store/retrieve the document on the disk, you have to go through one of the elasticsearch API to store/retrieve your document.

I think the documents are converted in a binary format. And I think the decision of hiding the files behind the API is to protect the integrity of the content, especially when working with replicated content (so that all nodes have the same content) and in order to be sure that the inverted index always reflect the real content on disk.
[citation needed]